# How to increase max. file descriptors / max. open files in Catalina?

Tags: catalina, filesystem

When using SourceTree I run into the following error shortly after using it:

```
It appears that the system has run out of file descriptors as described in this bug report: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1387401.
```

There are several resources online that describe [how to change the open file limit on past MacOS versions](https://gist.github.com/tombigel/d503800a282fcadbee14b537735d202c), but none seem to work on Catalina. Does anyone know how to increase this maximum in Catalina?

**Update:** After reading some more, it seemed that configuring the machine to work in "performance mode for macOS Server" might be the correct way to do this. However, [Apple's instructions on how to do this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202528) don't seem to work in Catalina either.

Comment: The [load.sh](https://gist.github.com/tombigel/d503800a282fcadbee14b537735d202c#file-load-sh) of the linked github page works perfectly here (server 10.15.3).

Comment: I previously executed those steps manually, but in case I missed something I tried running `load.sh` as well. And still, if I run `ulimit -a`, my `file descriptors` are fixed to `10240`. Even after reboot. I cannot get that to change no matter what I try. At what value are yours?

Comment: Performance mode won't work on non-server hardware and/or without Server.app installed. Also tested the 8 commands manually in a 10.15.3 Client (Virtual Machine 4 GB memory) and it works - do you get  any errors in the system.log or the global log?

Comment: I'm getting `com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (limit.maxfiles): The ServiceIPC key is no longer respected. Please remove it.` in the system.log. And for maxproc as well. There is no global.log. In addition I'm getting `sudo: setrlimit(8): Invalid argument` on the command line. Removing the `ServiceIPC key` gets rid of the error. But `ulimit -a` keeps reporting `-n: file descriptors 10240`. Even after shutdown and boot. I'm trying this on a MBP 16" with 64GB.

Comment: With global log (**no dot!**) I meant the unified log...

Comment: Of course. Sorry about that. No, there is no specific message to be found on unified level only the one from system.log.

Comment: Unfortunately I still did not find a working solution for this and I kept getting these terrible hangups over this issue. So I decided to do a completely fresh Catalina install. And eureka! That seems to have solved the problem. I've been running 3 weeks straight without ever running into this issue. So in short: for me this was the only working solution.